# how to upades a data into a database [edit user info]

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm tying to create an apps in android which will allow the user to edit the personal info and save it again and it must override the old info....i tried  but i didnt win :(.. im new in android please help here my code....

database.../////

//--updates a record--
public boolean updateRecords(long rowId, String NAME ,String SURNAME,
                                   String DateOfBirth,  String HomeAddress,String EmailNO,
                                   String PhoneNumber, String City,String TypePayment,
                                   String ShippingType,String CardNumber,String Username, String Passwords )

{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

```
args.put(COLUMN_NAME,NAME);
args.put(COLUMN_SURNAME,SURNAME);
args.put(COLUMN_DATE_OF_BIRTH,DateOfBirth);
args.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS,HomeAddress);
args.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,EmailNO);
args.put(COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER,PhoneNumber);
args.put(COLUMN_CITY,City);
args.put(COLUMN_PTYE_PAYMENT,TypePayment);
args.put(COLUMN_SHIPPING_TYPE,ShippingType);
args.put(COLUMN_CARD_NUMBER,CardNumber);
args.put(COLUMN_username,Username); 
args.put(COLUMN_Password,Passwords);


return db.update(USERS_TABLE, args,COLUMN_ID + "= "+ rowId,null)>0;

}
```

and i dont know how to update it in a ACTIVITY CLASS.. help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You call bad update method**

This `db.update(USERS_TABLE, args,COLUMN_ID + "= "+ rowId,null)` is dangerous, replace this with it, maybe will be problem with this. If it won't work, problem will be elsewhere.

```
db.update(USERS_TABLE, args, COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(rowID)}) > 0;
```

Comment: yeah, edited, i use bad word but it's dangerous and dirty written.

Comment: In fact, it's dangerous but it's just a simple solution to his question. So +1 for your comment :)

Comment: when you wanna be successfull developer, never tell it's easier but do with maximum performance.

Comment: yeah :-) this is my phase :-D

Comment: owk! you know i cant get the answer that you gave me where can I put this class because if i'm putting it in my ACTIVITY it giving me error...like my INSERT it wants me to return parameters please make me understand please be clear

Comment: post here your error log but if it throws error, you doing something wrong.

Comment: the whole code is an error... where I supose to put it, Activity class right?..if yes it giving me an error I cant even ran it :(

Comment: eish! I understand you now... i need a code for activity class.. BUTTON ONCLICK

Comment: I did gave it, the problem im having i dont know how to code the class that will call that updates in DB.. that what i need

Comment: It 2 long just give me ur email address i will email it nto you

Comment: so put it somwhere for example on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

You should know the contact id in-order to update that.

http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Android-Contacts/ is also helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: To be honest to you I dont see anything there for updates...and you spoke about contact id, what you mean please help